# Webdriver.get(url) open Firefox but not the URL

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, webdriver, surf

I am using this code in Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
driver.get("www.google.com")
```

Unlucky, this open Firefox but not the URL (not return any error). 
Do you know why?

Comment: try this driver.get(" https ://www.google.com")

Comment: don't work :( ..

Comment: any error you are getting ?

Comment: no error at all...

Comment: I think it's the binary. Download the appropriate [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and when instantiating `webdriver.Firefox` use `executable_path='path_to_your_geckodriver'`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **`Selenium 3.x`** along with the recent **`Frirefox Quantum`** browsers, you have to download **`geckodriver.exe`** from [this location](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) place it in your system and mention the absolute location of the **`geckodriver`** binary through the argument **`executable_path`** as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
driver.quit()
```