# Python Selenium Firefox Accessibility issue

Tags: python, selenium

I tried selenium in Python to open a Google page, however, instead of loading the page, the Firefox browser keeps telling me the Accessibility issue. I followed the instruction to change the settings but can not find it!

Besides, I found a solution to a similar problem - [Webdriver.get(url) open Firefox but not the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045412/webdriver-geturl-open-firefox-but-not-the-url), but after I linked geckodriver, the Accessibility problem is till there.

Could someone please help? Tens of Thanks in advance!!!!!

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'path\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('http://www.google/com')
```

[Screenshot - Accessibility issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHrwl.jpg)
[Screenshot - Firefox instruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3Znc.jpg)
[Screenshot - Can not find the setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Pr8z.jpg)